# Display record between two dates

Tags: jsp, date, odbc

Iam using msaccess and jsp. I want to display all records whose current value is sysdate or greater than 2 weeks of sysdate.For trial I compare todate with sysdate. But it is showing NUll pinter Exception.

```
      <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
      <%@ page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
       <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>


<%

         java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
      java.util.Date currentDate =new java.util.Date();
         java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime());
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       String sSql ="SELECT ADDRESS,FinancialYear,Todate from backup where Todate=?";
      String sDBQ = "C://Users/vishnu priya/Documents/amc.mdb";
     String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + sDBQ                  + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
      Connection cn = null;
     Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
   PreparedStatement pre=null;
       try {
             cn = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
                pre = cn.prepareStatement(sSql);
          pre.setDate(1,sqlDate);
           %>
       <table border='2' vspace='80'>
        <%
         out.println("<thead>");
          out.println("<tr>");
         out.println("<th>Customer Name</th>");
         out.println("<th>Financial Year</th>");
          out.println("<th>To Date</th>");
         out.println("</tr>");
        out.println(" </thead>");
        String add="";
        String fin="";
       String to="";
         while(rs.next())
             {
          add=rs.getString(1);
        fin=rs.getString(2);
        to=rs.getString(3);

         %>
          <tr>


        <td><%=add%></td>
         <td><%=fin%></td>
       <td><%=to%></td>
         <%
    }
     cn.close();

      }
   catch(Exception e)
     {
     out.println(e);
 e.printStackTrace();
       }
     %>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: post your exception and stack traces

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
Customer Name  Financial Year  To Date

Comment: Can you pls post your full stack trace ? edit your question and add to it

Comment: I couldnot invoke stack trace. It is showing error " Caliberation data missing" Profiling cannot be started on this jdk.Please complete profiler caliberation first and start profiling again" Iam new to jsp. pls help

Comment: what is your netbeans version and are you trying this example from any sites .

Comment: My netbeans version is 6.8. I have combined codes That I  received from  this site

Comment: i couldnt see any link here and from your code it seems to be `connection leak` . add `cn.close` to your code

Comment: Added still showing the same error. What should I do to get stack trace so that you can help me out

Comment: Check to your question , i have edited it

Comment: Class Name - Live Allocated Objects;"Live Bytes";"Live Objects";"Allocated Objects";"Avg. Age";"Generations"
char[];"1630408";"10550";"61318";"25.33";"66"
byte[];"333808";"514";"8353";"12.96";"34"
java.lang.String;"333312";"13888";"77774";"36.60";"66"
java.lang.Object[];"99960";"2430";"45357";"21.81";"58"
java.util.HashMap$Entry[];"90856";"1014";"6978";"21.59";"52"
java.lang.reflect.Method;"84400";"1055";"2402";"10.27";"26"
java.util.HashMap$Entry;"72120";"3005";"49403";"30.68";"58"
java.net.URI;"66960";"837";"2510";"4.69";"12"
int[];"52696";"489";"2688";"12.31";"29"

Comment: Kindly find stack trace above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have added cn.close as mentioned.But same error is showing. Please find the stack trace in the above